# How to print the current printing date and time along with the page number?

Tags: html, css, footer

I need the format like HH:MM:SS Date Time
With the help of css and html ,how can I show the page number and printing date and time in the footer of the page.

Comment: would you like to share the code ?

Comment: How would you do that with html and css only?

Comment: You can't. CSS and HTML are just ways to format and style your content. You need an actual programming language to provide programmatic content other than static.

Comment: Ok,..then how to do the same using javascript?

Comment: Do you have... something?

Comment: Till now i have used only static way to print the header and footer using <header > and <footer >

Comment: <header class="onlyprint">About Project </header>
<footer class="onlyprint"> XYZ </footer>

Answer (score 5):

By using HTML and CSS you can only write it by yourself but if you want it to be automated so you must use a server language like PHP or another.
You can also do it by using Javascript or Jquery like so :

```js
var d = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = d;
```

```html
<p id="date"></p>
```

Comment: How from javascript?

Comment: html `<p id="date"></p>`  
Javascript
`<script>
    var d = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
    document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = d;
</script>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use moment library to get a better display of the date on your jsreport

**first**, Install moment package inside your docker container

**second**, you need to allow custom script in your jsreport config.json by adding

`"allowedModules": "moment"` or  allow all `"allowedModules": "*"`

**Third**, import moment to your jsreport `var moment = require('moment')`

and finally, add a helper for the time and display it on your jsreport `{{now}}`

```
var moment = require('moment')


Handlebars.registerHelper("now", function(date) {
    return  moment(date).format('L');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Here how to achieve with css print media

Page numbering

css

```
@page {
  @bottom-right {
    content: "Page "counter(page);
  }
}
```